# React 15 setState next line does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

The react setState after action doesn't work.

```
handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({foo: 'bar'});  < - it working 
    console.log('hellow') < - does not working, console is clean 
}
```

As far i checked my state, I did everything right about the state values.

I don't know what is the problem

---- update----

The project that created a new create-react-app operates very normally.

I don't know why the above issue occurred, and it doesn't make sense in common sense, but it seems that it's because the project is so messed up.

Thank you for answering such limited situations.

Comment: this code is fine , error may be something else. debug

Comment: Yeah this is perfectly valid code and the `console.log` should be firing. If it's not somehow, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: is this problem possoble ?
promise.then( function (res) { setState() } ).bind(tihs) <- no arrow function , use bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct but you need to call handleChange() method
Ex :-

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.handleChange();
}

handleChange = () => {
  this.setState({ foo: "bar" });
  console.log("Hello");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
handleChange = () => {
  this.setState({ foo: "bar" }, () => {
    console.log("hellow");
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call callback in setState as below

```
handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({foo: 'bar'}, () => {
    console.log('hellow')
}); 

}
```

Comment: I know that way works. But i don't know why that specific part is not working.